# How to fix missing dynamic web page in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have installed eclipse Oxygen in windows  10. I don’t find the “dynamic web project” option under project list. I have already installed Web, XML, Java EE using below link

[How to fix Dynamic Web Project missing in Eclipse Oxygen](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/06/how-to-fix-dynamic-web-project-missing-in-eclipse-issue/)

How to fix missing dynamic web page in eclipse oxygen?

Comment: have you restarted eclipse afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Help --> Install New Software--> place this URL in work with field

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/

Select the list of software's which do you want to update and complete normal update process. Once, installation completed you have to restart the eclipse. So, you are able to create the Dynamic Web Project.

Thanks,